# Strange UIButton appearance

Tags: ios, swift, button, storyboard, assets

In my app I have a few UIButtons with images, they all behave as expected, except one. It should be shown like this:

[image]

When I run my app on simulator or real device, it's being shown like this:

[image]

I export it from Figma as 3X, put into Assets, tick Preserve Vector Data and choose Single Scale. Here are my Assets settings:

[image]

I've also tried downloading it as 1X and 2X image from Figma, but it didn't help.

Have you got any ideas why it's happening?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use that image from SF Symbol which is provided by apple.
Direct use it in imageView and you can also give constraint according to your requirement.
Otherwise you don't need to preserve vector data of image. So, try that also perhaps it will help you :).